# How to not trigger livedata on device rotation?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, geolocation, android-livedata

I'm learning android development with MVVM architecture.

I have my map and I can get my location but if i scroll on the map on my device screen, on rotation my focus go back to the initial location; how to stop liveData triggered to stay on my last position on map ?

Here is my viewModel :

```
@HiltViewModel
public class MapViewModel extends ViewModel {

    @NonNull
    private final LocationRepository locationRepository;
    @NonNull
    private final NearBySearchRepository nearBySearchRepository;



    @Inject
    public MapViewModel(@NonNull LocationRepository locationRepository, @NonNull NearBySearchRepository nearBySearchRepository
    ) {
        this.locationRepository = locationRepository;
        this.nearBySearchRepository = nearBySearchRepository;
    }

    public SingleLiveEvent<LatLng> getFocusOnUser() {
        SingleLiveEvent<LatLng> mediatorLiveData = new SingleLiveEvent<>();
        LiveData<Location> locationLiveData = locationRepository.getLocationLiveData();

        locationLiveData.getValue();
        mediatorLiveData.addSource(locationLiveData, location -> {
            if (location != null) {
                mediatorLiveData.removeSource(locationLiveData);
                mediatorLiveData.setValue(
                        new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())
                    );}
        });
        return mediatorLiveData;
    }
}
```

If someone can please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found what was wrong, i let my question if this can help someone.

First : my getter is still observed in my view but instead of doing all the work it just returns the value of my singleLiveEvent (badly called mediatorLiveData)

Then : i put all the work in my viewModel constructor

```
@HiltViewModel
public class MapViewModel extends ViewModel {

    @NonNull
    private final LocationRepository locationRepository;
    @NonNull
    private final NearBySearchRepository nearBySearchRepository;

    SingleLiveEvent<LatLng> mediatorLiveData = new SingleLiveEvent<>();
    MutableLiveData<Location> locationMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();


    @Inject
    public MapViewModel(@NonNull LocationRepository locationRepository, @NonNull NearBySearchRepository nearBySearchRepository
    ) {
        this.locationRepository = locationRepository;
        this.nearBySearchRepository = nearBySearchRepository;

        LiveData<Location> locationLiveData = locationRepository.getLocationLiveData();
        locationMutableLiveData.setValue(locationLiveData.getValue());

        mediatorLiveData.addSource(locationLiveData, location -> {
            if (location != null) {
                mediatorLiveData.removeSource(locationLiveData);
                mediatorLiveData.setValue(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
            }
        });
    }

    public SingleLiveEvent<LatLng> getFocusOnUser() {
        return mediatorLiveData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what has changed comparing to the code in the question. It is quiet difficult to see what is the solution here.